# Drupal 7 Override Image Alt and Title attributes

Tags: media, tokens

In Drupal 6 I used the [Imagefield Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens) module to set ALT and TITLE tags to default values if not specified (generally the node title).

I'm looking for applying this in Drupal 7, but I am having troubles. I found [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1053402), but it's a bit inconclusive.

Would it be possible to do this using a template preprocess or a field.tpl.php override?

Comment: As you are using an unregistered account, it is not kept between different browsers/computers. If you are using a different browser/computer, you are using a different account. That is the reason you cannot comment to answers given to your questions. This also means that your reputation is not kept, if you clear the cookies in your browser.

Answer (score 6):

I think a template preprocess would be fine for this, specifically `hook_preprocess_image()`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$vars) {
  // alt
  if (empty($vars['attributes']['alt'])) {
    $vars['attributes']['alt'] = DEFAULT_IMAGE_ALT;
  }

  // title
  if (empty($vars['attributes']['title'])) {
    $vars['attributes']['title'] = DEFAULT_IMAGE_TITLE;
  }
}
```

Pretty much all images (including those provided by a field) run through [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) so this is pretty much the best place for your code.

Comment: Thanks Clive - I was thinking that it might be something like that - just wrapping my head around the whole preprocess layer at the moment! With Drupal, the learning curve never seems to end...

Comment: Coudld you somehow get the node title from that? I'd like to use it in the tag.